# Bash If then that reads a list in a file condition

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

Here is the condition:

I have a file with all packages installed. 
I have a folder with all kinds of other packages, but they include all of the ones in the list, plus more. 
I need a bash script that will read the file and check a folder for packages that don't exist in the list then remove them, they are not needed, but keep the packages that are on the list in that folder.

Or perhaps the bash should read folder then if packages in the folder aren't on the list them rm -f that or those packages.

I am familiar with writing if then conditional statements, I just don't know how to do if making the items in the list a variable or variables (in a loop).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want something like this:

```
for file in $(ls folder) ; do
  grep -E "$file" install-list-file >/dev/null || \
    echo $file
done > rm-list

vi rm-list # view file to ensure correct
rm $(<rm_list)
```

There are ways to make this faster (using parameter substitution to avoid fork/exec's), but I recommend avoiding fancy shell stuff [${file##*/}] until you've got the basics down.  Also, this script basically translates the description into a script and is not intended to be much more than a guide on how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the packages on the list to a new folder, delete the original folder, and move the temporary folder back:

```
DIR=directory-name
mkdir "$DIR-tmp"
while read pkgname; do
   if [[ -f "$DIR/$pkgname" ]]; then
       mv "$DIR/$pkgname" "$DIR-tmp"
   fi
done < package-list.txt

# Confirm $DIR-tmp has the files you want first!
rm -rf "$DIR"
mv "$DIR-tmp" "$DIR"
```